# Using Compositing's File Output Node to batch render videos?

Tags: rendering

As I understand it (but correct me if I'm wrong as I'm a beginner), there are two ways to batch-render multiple scenes (so that I can launch overnight without having to baby sit.

1. Laying the scenes back to back in the sequencer of a new scene and export that.

2.Using he compositing "file output" nodes and plug all my scenes to that.

I'm going for option 2 cause I need separate files for each scenes (reconnecting them back and fort into my editing software).

However I need to export in video format (h264 mov for example), because exporting image sequence and reassembling is an extra step I don't have the luxury to do on this project.Problem is, I don't find video settings in the export properties of the node.

Can you please help me or perhaps suggest another way?

Thanks in advance

Comment: of course there are more methods...e.g. writing your own python script...or use a fantastic free existing one (add-on - which is a python script). I am using loom (you can search on github or google for it) and i think it is amazing and easy to use. Maybe try out?

Comment: Thanks. It looks like Loom doesn't render straight to video, only image sequence, which can then be converted to video.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out the third and best way to batch render my scenes is by using the command line. It's actually not that hard.

I wrote as many commands as I have scenes on a text fileand pasted the all thing in the terminal. Works like a charm.

Found everything I needed in the manual:
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/command_line/index.html

Comment: Include the commands in your answer to make it full.